# Ubuntu 12.10 Gnome Shell Title Bar Fonts

Tags: gnome, 12.10, fonts

The font in my 12.10 Gnome Shell title bar is displaying some characters incorrectly (see snapshot).

This behavior happened once before, but logging back in fixed it.

I installed some xfonts in order to fix a MATLAB bug (xfonts-100dpi and
xfonts-75dpi). After that, the title bar bug appeared and won't go away, even after logging in and out.

Any ideas?

Screenshot:
      [image]

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).